# $e$ popping up in topic I'm unfamiliar with

Tags: algorithms, random, computational-mathematics

I programmed up a little algorithm that goes like this:

1. Fix two positive, real numbers, call them $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
2. Generate a new, random, real number, $x \in [0,1]$
3. Set $\alpha$ = $x\alpha\beta$,
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until $\alpha$ is equal to the smallest float supported (I'll just call this 0), or $\alpha$ is equal to the largest float supported (I'll call this $\infty$).

Initially I thought this would turn up nonsense, or only occasionally go to 0 or infinity.

But after experimenting a lot with values of $\beta$, I found a fascinating result:

If $\beta \in (0,e)$, $\alpha$ always goes to $0$.

If $\beta=e$, $\alpha$ goes to $0$ about 50% of the time, and to $\infty$ about 50% of the time.

If $\beta \in (e,\infty)$, $\alpha$ always goes to $\infty$.

Now these are all results based on running the above algorithm about 10,000 times, so maybe I'm in the wrong to put 'always', but certainly most of the time these results hold.

This was surprising to me! I'm not well versed in randomness, or computational mathematics, or probability so I can't really fathom why $e$ would pop up so prominently in this context. Can anyone point me towards the subject I need to examine to understand this result?

(Apologies if this post is mistagged, as I said, I'm not experienced with the subjects this post related to)

Comment: The implementation I've written is in Ruby, using the Random.rand method. I'm not familiar with PRNGs, but documentation says "PRNGs are currently implemented as a modified Mersenne Twister with a period of 2**19937-1."

This all generates a random float between 0 and 1, which I then multiply by $\beta$.

Comment: I think you are multiplying by a number between $0$ and $\beta$ at each stage, right?  If so, you need to either write "$x\in[0,1]$" in step 2 or remove the factor of $\beta$ in step 3.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I've modified step 2.

Comment: The crucial insight is that if a random variable $X$ is chosen from a uniform distribution from $[0, 1]$, then $-\ln X$ is from an exponential distribution with mean $1$. (And this is how $e$ pops up.) And so, when you multiply by $\beta$, it matters whether $\ln \beta$ has mean more than $1$ or not; this determines whether it offsets $\ln X$ with mean $-1$ or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a fixed $\beta$, your algorithm can be stated as follows:

- Pick $\alpha_0$ arbitrarily.
- For each $n \ge 1$, generate a uniformly random real number $X_n$ in $[0, 1]$ and set $\alpha_n = X_n\alpha_{n-1}\beta$.

Thus each $\alpha_n$ is got by multiplying the previous $\alpha_{n-1}$ by $\beta X_i$, so
$$\alpha_n = \alpha_0\beta^n X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n \tag 1$$

Things become more tractable/familiar if we take logarithms, to convert products into sums: each $\log \alpha_n$ is got by taking the previous $\log \alpha_{n-1}$ and adding $\log\beta + \log X_i$, so we get the logarithmic version of $(1)$:
$$\log \alpha_n = \log \alpha_0 + n\log\beta + \sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i \tag 2$$

Thus the sequence $\log \alpha_n$ is a [random walk](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap07.pdf) starting at $\log \alpha_0$ and changing by $Y_i = \log \beta + \log X_i$ at each step. For such a random walk $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, its eventual behaviour is determined by whether $E[Y_i]$ is positive, negative, or zero.

We can in fact determine the distribution of $\log X_i$ (and therefore of $Y_i$). Each $X_i$ is [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) in $[0, 1]$. It turns out, this means that $(-\ln X_i)$ is [exponentially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with mean $1$. Let's derive that. To find the distribution of $\log_b X_i$ (taking logarithms to arbitrary base $b$ to be clear on where $e$ pops up), we we can calculate the cumulative distribution function: for $t \le 0$ (assuming wlog that $b > 1$), we have $\Pr(\log_b X_i \le t) = \Pr(X_i \le b^t) = b^t$. Differentiating this wrt $t$ gives the probability density function, which is $b^t\ln b$ (and $0$ for $t > 0$). In particular,
$$
\operatorname{E}[\log_b X_i] 
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} t \, b^t\ln b \, dt 
= - 1/\ln b = -\log_b e.
$$

**This is where $e$ pops up**: although to convert products into sums we could have taken logarithm to any base $b$, the fact is that $E[\log_b X_i] = -\log_b e$, so $e$ pops up unavoidably (and we might as well take the natural logarithm).

So $E[Y_i] = \log\beta + \log X_i = \log \beta - \log e$ (whatever base we choose), which is positive, negative or zero depending on whether $\beta > e$, $\beta < e$ or $\beta = e$. It is therefore intuitively clear that when $\beta > e$ the random walk $\log\alpha_n$ drifts towards $\infty$ (and $\alpha_n$ towards $\infty$ as well) and when $\beta < e$ towards $-\infty$ (and $\alpha_n$ towards $0$). Proofs of precise statements below.

---

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log X_i$. We have, from the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) applied to the independent and identically distributed random variables $\log X_i$, the fact ("a.s." stands for ["almost surely"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)) that 
$$\frac{S_n}{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} - 1.$$

This means that, with probability $1$, we have
$$\frac{\log \alpha_n}{n} = \frac{\log \alpha_0}{n} + \log \beta + \frac{S_n}{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} \log \beta - 1$$

In your problem, we iterate until either $\alpha_n$ hits an upper threshold or hits a lower threshold, and we record which threshold it hit. (Typical example thresholds induced by programming languages are on the order of $10^{38}$ and $10^{-38}$ for [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), and $10^{308}$ and $10^{-308}$ for [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).) In particular,

- when $\beta < e$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log \alpha_n}{n} < 0$ almost surely, which means that $a_n \to 0$ almost surely (and thus it is more likely to hit the upper threshold),
- when $\beta > e$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log \alpha_n}{n} = c > 0$ almost surely (where $c = \log\beta - 1$), which means that $a_n \to \infty$ almost surely ($\alpha_n$ grows like $e^{nc} \to \infty$) (and thus it is more likely to hit the upper threshold).

For the case when $\beta = e$, see below.

---

Note however that as our thresholds are not exactly $0$ and $\infty$ (neither of which is achievable anyway), we can only say "more likely" above: the fact that almost surely $a_n \to 0$ doesn't necessarily mean that the sequence $a_n$ hits $10^{-308}$ before $10^{308}$: it is possible (just very unlikely) that it does reach $10^{308}$ before $10^{-308}$, but eventually approaches $0$.

I don't know how to fix this, but at least for the $\beta = e$ case, the [theory of random walks (see section 9.4)](http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/documents/6.262vdbw9.pdf) has some help. Let $Y_i = \log\beta + X_i$, and let $T_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} Y_i$ (using $T_n$ to avoid confusion with the earlier $S_n$) so that $T_n$ is a random walk, and $\log\alpha_n = \log\alpha_0 + T_n$. Then if the lower threshold is $L$ and the upper threshold is $U$, the stopping events $\alpha_n \le L$ and $\alpha_n \ge U$ are equivalent to $T_n \le \log L - \log \alpha_0 = L'$ and $T_n \ge \log U + \log\alpha_0 = U'$.

For the special case when $\operatorname{E}[Y_i] = 0$ (this means $\beta = e$), we have, denoting $J$ as the stopping time, $\operatorname{E}[S_J] = \operatorname{E}[J]\operatorname{E}[Y_i] = 0$ ([Wald's equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation)), which roughly gives, assuming that $S_J$ is either roughly $L'$ or $U'$ (i.e., $\alpha_J$ doesn't overshoot the thresholds by too much) that $0 = \operatorname{E}[S_J] = p_{L'}L' + (1-p_{L'})U'$ so $p_{L'} = \frac{U'}{U'-L'} = \frac{\log U + \log\alpha_0}{\log U - \log L + 2\log \alpha_0}$ which for the thresholds from the single-precision floating format $U \approx 3.4 × 10^{38}$ and $L = 2^{−149}$ gives roughly $\frac{88.7 + \log \alpha_0}{192.0 + 2\log\alpha_0}$ which at least for values of $\log\alpha_0$ small in magnitude gives roughly $0.46$ rather than $0.5$ exactly (though it's much closer to $0.50$ if you take your $L$ to be the smallest [normalized number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_number) $2^{-126}$ instead).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a detailed response. You've given me a great basis for understanding this thing.

Comment: @TamTamTam: Actually I think there is more to say here... look back in a day or so; there may be more answers here (or even a bit more in my answer :p).

Comment: Gee. Thanks for taking such interest. I've set a reminder to check back soon.

Comment: If $\alpha_{n}=X_{n}\alpha_{n-1}\beta$, then $\alpha_{n}=\alpha_{0}\beta X_1 \beta X_2 \cdots \beta X_n$.  You are missing many $\beta$'s.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Thanks for pointing that out: the OP had a mistake in the question, and coincidentally I had the same mistake in my code. I have now reinstated the many missing $\beta$s.

Comment: My code that simulates this (with sample output) is here: https://github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/blob/master/log-convergence.py

Comment: I do think there is still something interesting going on, which is that the simulation doesn't show a sharp transition around $\beta = e$.

Comment: By sharp transition do you mean that when using values around $\beta=e$, the limit of $a_n$ can tend to any case, all $0$, all $\infty$ or some combination of the two?

Comment: I think that it is OK now. Your code's behaviour around $e$ also interests me, so I will give it a try in an online compiler while on cellphone, and will comment here the result if I survive to such an adventure :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have $\alpha_{i+1}=\alpha_{i} X_{i+1}$, where $X_i\sim U(0,\beta)$; so $\alpha_{n}=\alpha_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$.  The infinite product (and hence $\alpha_n$) diverges to $+\infty$ if its logarithm,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log X_i,
$$
does, and by the law of large numbers this occurs almost surely if $E[\log X_i]>0$.  Now,
$$
E[\log X_i]=\frac{1}{\beta}\int_{0}^{\beta}\log x dx=\log(\beta)-1=\log(\beta/e),
$$
which is positive when $\beta>e$.  Similarly, the product diverges to $0$ if its logarithm diverges to $-\infty$, which occurs almost surely if $\beta < e$.  Finally, if $\beta=e$ exactly, you have an unbiased one-dimensional random walk, which implies that $\alpha_n$ neither converges nor diverges: with probability $1$, it crosses $1$ (that is, goes from larger than $1$ to smaller, or vice-versa) infinitely many times.

Comment: OP's observation… that the cutoff is $\beta=e$… can only be correct if there's something wrong with how the question is written.  My guess is that the recursion is actually $\alpha_{i+1}=\alpha_{i}x_{i+1}$; i.e., the extra "$\beta$" is extraneous.

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  $X$ is uniformly chosen from $[0,\beta^2]$.

Comment: This looks right +1 - my code shows somewhere $\beta \approx 1.65$ as the cutoff.  Will think more on this.

Comment: @Macavity: Was about to leave this comment on your deleted answer: By the way, why do you run it for a fixed number `NMax` of iterations, instead of until it hits a threshold (as in the question)? And are you visually inspecting the value of `a` at the end of your `NMax` iterations, or averaging it over different runs (in which case the expected value will become relevant)?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR and Macavity can you please share your full source code? I would like to contrast them and see if I find something.(I don't have a particular simulation result to share, as I am using phone right now )

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Once $a=\alpha$ hits inf or 0, it stays there, so NMax just needs to be large enough.  And no, I am not averaging it.  Anyway, the error in your post if you correct you will get the same $\beta = \sqrt{e}$ cutoff, which seems to agree with simulation as well.

Comment: @chubakueno: I've shared my code [here](https://github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/blob/master/log-convergence.py).

Comment: @Macavity: But I do get interesting behaviour around $\beta = e$ with [simulation](https://github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/blob/master/log-convergence.py), so that's what is surprising. Anyway, the OP has just changed the question (to get rid of a factor of $\beta$), so I'll edit my answer a bit, but let's continue to puzzle this out.

Comment: @chubakueno the code i used is simply {
    int i, NMax = 100000;
    double a=1, b=1.65, x;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (i = 1; i < NMax; i++){
        x = (double) random() /RAND_MAX *b;
        a *= x*b;
    }
    printf("a = %f \n", a);
    return 0;
    }

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Looks to me your code generates X uniformly in $(0, 1)$, not in $(0, \beta)$.  Do check.  That would of course explain exactly why you get the cutoff $\beta = e$.

Comment: @Macavity: Oh you're right. I just made the same mistake the OP made. Let me fix everything. :-(

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice the error until @mjqxxxx pointed it out. That was some amazing deduction!

Comment: What is the central limit theorem you're using that gives almost sure convergence? (Ah, you're using the fact that the mean goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$, so the probability of being within some fixed finite interval goes to $0$?)

Comment: The central limit theorem says that the average (here $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log X_i$) converges almost surely to $E[\log X]$.  If $E[\log X] > 0$, this convergence implies that the sum and the original product diverge to $+\infty$.  If $E[\log X]<0$, it implies that the sum diverges to $-\infty$ and the original product diverges to $0$.  If $E[\log X]=0$, it's inconclusive: the sum is a.s. $o(n)$, but it could remain bounded, or could diverge more slowly.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: The central limit theorem I know, which is also what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralLimitTheorem.html) have, is about convergence in distribution, not almost surely. The fact that the average $\frac1n \sum_i X_i$ for IID $X_i$'s converges almost surely to $\operatorname{E}[X_1]$ is given by the [Strong Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_law_of_large_numbers). At least, this is the terminology that's familiar to me.

Comment: You're right; the (stronger) central limit theorem isn't necessary here.  Either the strong or weak law of large numbers is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm I think the weak law of large numbers is not sufficient if we want almost sure convergence. Also, I don't see how to conclude almost sure convergence from the usual central limit theorem. Sorry if there is something obvious I'm missing, but as far as I know, convergence in distribution is weaker than almost sure convergence....